# all, upto children selector

Tags: css, css-selectors

I want to apply the border-bottom for each children of the div but unknown divs (each div has padding value, so the border effect would look something extra) are there inside starting from parent div and children div.

[image]

So, as in the picture above, I wanted to select `.main` and all child divs of main upto `.child` div.

So, for the first example code in the picture result would be like this:

[image]

---

There is purely another reason behind this ( to select upto specific child ) , but to make it easy, I've illustrated like the above one.

I can only hope that this feature get implemented in the future:

```
.main, .main >> div.child{ /*where >> would be upto direct child selector*/
   border-bottom: 1px solid blue;
   padding-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Comment: I doubt there is CSS-only solution for that. You can, however, iterate over each div from `.child` up to `.main` and add any custom class / appearance with [jQuery.parent()](http://api.jquery.com/parent/) or similar.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this by doing overwriting styling for children of `.child`

It will look something like following.

```
.main, .main div{
    border-bottom: 1px solid red;
}
.child div{
    border-bottom: none;
}
```

[(JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/sws6x80u/)